# How to pivot this parent child tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I would like to ask for help for pivoting this Parent child table.

My Parent-Child table:

```
parent  child
ve1      vet12 
ve1      vet13
vet12    adm1
vet13    adm2
adm2     xyz
ve2      vy1
vx       kit1
```

I want to pivot the Parent-Child table into this table:

```
level1  level2  level3  level4
 ve1     vet12   adm1
 ve1     vet13   adm2    xyz
 ve2     vy1
 vx      kit1
```

However my test query still doesn't work.

---

my test :

```
SELECT
    L1.child as ID
    L1.parent as Level1
    L2.parent as Level2
    L3.parent as Level3
    L4.parent as Level4
FROM
    Hierarchy as L1

        INNER JOIN
    Hierarchy as L2
        ON L1.child = L2.parent

        INNER JOIN
    Hierarchy as L3
        ON L2.child = L3.parent

        INNER JOIN
    Hierarchy as L4
        ON L3.child = L4.parent
```

I have tested only 4 level, but in the real database, the number of level may change.

---

Table for test:

```
CREATE TABLE Hierarchy(
    parent  VARCHAR(20),
    child VARCHAR(20))



  INSERT INTO Hierarchy VALUES ('ve1','vet12'),
('ve1' ,'vet13'),
('vet12','adm1'),
('vet13','adm2'),
('adm2','xyz'),
('ve2','vy1'),
('vx','kit1')
```

Comment: If you know there are up to four levels you can just use `join`s.

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns shouldn't change, so you need to specify a definitive amount of them. You need to change your JOINs to OUTER JOINs to allow having hierarchies with less levels than the maximum.

```
SELECT
    L1.parent AS Level1,
    L1.child  AS Level2,
    L2.child  AS Level3,
    L3.child  AS Level4,
    L4.child  AS Level5
FROM      Hierarchy as L1
LEFT JOIN Hierarchy as L2 ON L1.child = L2.parent
LEFT JOIN Hierarchy as L3 ON L2.child = L3.parent
LEFT JOIN Hierarchy as L4 ON L3.child = L4.parent
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT Child FROM Hierarchy h WHERE h.child = L1.Parent);
```

Comment: Thankyou Luis, your Query looks good. but actually the number of level may vary so i can't fix it with 5 levels. i need a dynamic recursive Query

Comment: That's going to be a lot of overhead. You might want to plan on having this done on the display layer.